# Requests coming from IPad "sometimes" come as Mozilla 0

Tags: ipad, http, web-applications, user-agent, browser-detection

Now, this sounds very strange but we have an application which supports only particular browsers and in order to keep a close look on alll the requests coming, we have a log server which logs all the detailed information about incoming request's userAgent.

Now, some of the IPad users complained that they used to see NotSupported.html page, which is the page we redirect users to when the page is not supported. They ONLY see it sometime.

We we looked at our logs and sometimes Ipad requests were coming a Mozilla 0.

I am using HTTpRequesBase's UserAgent Property to read it. and I am not sure why IPad identifies it self as mozilla 0 and that also ONLY sometimes. Anyone ahd similar experince?

Answer (score 0):

Safari is not the only Browser in the Apple devices.

When I go with my Chrome for iPhone to http://www.whatsmyuseragent.com it shows Mozilla as well. So the best assumption is that those users are not using Safari.

EDIT: It does come with enough information to know it is an iPad, I myself have a project that matches iPad in the User-Agent string and works for Chrome/Safari and I don't have Opera to test right now but I guess it works too (anecdotal on no complaints).

Comment: No.... one of them is sitting in front of me and he does not have Miozilla even installed.